# How to join 3 table eloquent laravel 8

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

i have 3 tables

**user**

```
user_id
name_user
contacts
request_id
```

**request_register**

```
request_id
user_id
team_id
```

**team**

```
team_id
name_team
```

i want get list of user details who register to team with spesific id, example:

**team with id 1**

| id_user | name_user | contacts | team_id | name_team |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | michael | 1234 | 1 | phoenix |
| 2 | john | 1232 | 1 | phoenix |
| 3 | cindy | 1222 | 1 | phoenix |

Comment: define appropriate relations in User model and requestRegister models then use User::with('request_register.team')->get();

Answer (score 0):

You can use [whereHas()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method provided by Laravel, but you have to specify the relationships needed to query using the method, probably like this:

```
$teamId = //retrieve the team id...;
$users = User::whereHas('request_register', function() (Builder $query) use ($teamId) {
   $query->where('team_id', $teamId);
})->get();
```

This will automatically make a join between `users` and `request_register` to get what you want to get.